# Как задать картинке синеватый оттенок в ксс?

Tags: css

у меня вопрос, как я могу задать картинке такой синеватый оттенок через ксс?

Comment: какой такой оттенок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как вариант:

```css
div {position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;}
div img {filter: drop-shadow(2px 3px 5px blue);}
div:after {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
transition: background 0.8s;
}
div:hover:after {background: rgba(0,0,255,0)}
div:hover img {filter: drop-shadow(2px 3px 5px black);}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://dnevnyk-uspeha.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/interesnye-fakty-o-koshkah-o-kotoryh-vy-ne-znali.jpg"></div>
```

Или ещё вариант:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  transition: background 0.8s;
}

div img {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(1);
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 3px 5px blue);
}

div:hover {background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)}
div:hover img {filter: drop-shadow(2px 3px 5px black);}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://dnevnyk-uspeha.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/interesnye-fakty-o-koshkah-o-kotoryh-vy-ne-znali.jpg"></div>
```